# browser-sync + gulp reloading in chrome

Tags: gulp, stylus, browser-sync

Before asking here i tried to find similar subject on overstockflow but it didn't help much. So, here is my subject. I'm using **browser-sync + gulp** and have problems with reload and watch. I have gulpfile and when I run gulp, it should watch and reload the all changes that happens but doesn't. It compiles but stop watching farther and gives me notification. I have to reload my page in browser manually what is not handy, Here is my code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    jade = require ('gulp-jade'),
    stylus = require ('gulp-stylus'),
    watch = require ('gulp-watch'),
    plumber =  require('gulp-plumber'),
    browserSync = require ('browser-sync').create(),
    poststylus = require ('poststylus'),
    lost = require ('lost');

// JADE
gulp.task('jade', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/jade/*.jade')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(jade({pretty:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
});

// STYLUS
gulp.task('stylus', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/stylus/*.styl')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(stylus({use:[poststylus(['lost'])]}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'))
});

gulp.task('browser-watch', ['jade', 'stylus'], browserSync.reload);


gulp.task('serve', function(){

    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('app/jade/*.jade', 'app/stylus/*.styl', ['browser-watch']);
});


// DEFUALT
gulp.task('default', ['browser-watch', 'serve']);
```

here is notification:

```
$ gulp
    [20:34:23] Using gulpfile c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\gulpfile.js
    [20:34:23] Starting 'jade'...
    [20:34:23] Starting 'stylus'...
    [20:34:23] Starting 'serve'...
    [20:34:23] 'serve' errored after 239 μs
    [20:34:23] TypeError: object is not a function
        at Gulp.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\gulpfile.js:31:2)
        at module.exports (c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (c:\Users\Bogdan\Desktop\projects\lost\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
        at c:\Users\Bogdan\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:129:20
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
        at startup (node.js:129:16)
        at node.js:814:3
    Container#eachAtRule is deprecated. Use Container#walkAtRules instead.
    Container#eachDecl is deprecated. Use Container#walkDecls instead.
    Node#removeSelf is deprecated. Use Node#remove.
    [20:34:23] Finished 'jade' after 412 ms
    [20:34:23] Finished 'stylus' after 390 ms
```

any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Deprecate container#remove and node#removeSelf. Fixes #191.](https://github.com/postcss/postcss/commit/cdae155901b92c08ad825472a6cbfabcd6f4c52e)

Answer (score 0):

I know this part is wrong in your 'serve' task:

`gulp.watch('app/jade/*.jade', 'app/stylus/*.styl', ['browser-watch']);`

should put the sources in an array to watch 'multiple files'

`gulp.watch(['app/jade/*.jade', 'app/stylus/*.styl'], ['browser-watch']);`

On another note, I didn't know about 'poststylus'. That looks awesome! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in poststylus but in lost plugin, its 100%. The version of lost that you use now in your project used deprecated methods of postcss. 
Try to delete it from your package and then to add it (or simply update):
sudo npm uninstall --save-dev lost
sudo npm install --save-dev lost

It worked for me - the notification of deprecated removeSelf disappeared.

The issue was solved 2 days ago: https://github.com/corysimmons/lost/pull/169

Comment: thanks, since my terminal dosn't read the command 'sudo' (don't know why) I tried to reinstall it without it.